# How to calculate accuracy in training RNN language model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm using this word level RNN langauge model  here: https://github.com/hunkim/word-rnn-tensorflow

How to calculate the accuracy of RNN model in each epoch.

Following is the code in training that shows training loss and other things in each epoch:

```
for e in range(model.epoch_pointer.eval(), args.num_epochs):
        sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, args.learning_rate * (args.decay_rate ** e)))
        data_loader.reset_batch_pointer()
        state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
        speed = 0
        if args.init_from is None:
            assign_op = model.epoch_pointer.assign(e)
            sess.run(assign_op)
        if args.init_from is not None:
            data_loader.pointer = model.batch_pointer.eval()
            args.init_from = None
        for b in range(data_loader.pointer, data_loader.num_batches):
            start = time.time()
            x, y = data_loader.next_batch()
            feed = {model.input_data: x, model.targets: y, model.initial_state: state,
                    model.batch_time: speed}
            summary, train_loss, state, _, _ = sess.run([merged, model.cost, model.final_state,
                                                         model.train_op, model.inc_batch_pointer_op], feed)
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, e * data_loader.num_batches + b)
            speed = time.time() - start
            if (e * data_loader.num_batches + b) % args.batch_size == 0:
                print("{}/{} (epoch {}), train_loss = {:.3f}, time/batch = {:.3f}" \
                    .format(e * data_loader.num_batches + b,
                            args.num_epochs * data_loader.num_batches,
                            e, train_loss, speed))
            if (e * data_loader.num_batches + b) % args.save_every == 0 \
                    or (e==args.num_epochs-1 and b == data_loader.num_batches-1): # save for the last result
                checkpoint_path = os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'model.ckpt')
                saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step = e * data_loader.num_batches + b)
                print("model saved to {}".format(checkpoint_path))
train_writer.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the model has both targets and prediction probabilities for each class. 
You can reduce the probabilities tensor to keep the class index of the highest probability.

```
predictions = tf.cast(tf.argmax(model.probs, axis=2), tf.int32)
```

Then you can compare to the targets, to know if it successfully predicted or not:

```
correct_preds = tf.equal(predictions, model.targets)
```

Finally the accuracy is the ratio between correct prediction over the size of input, aka mean of this boolean tensor.

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))
```

Comment: i got an error in 
    correct_preds = tf.equal(predictions, model.targets)
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 31215 and 25 for 'Equal' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [31215], [50,25].
can't find any solution to this

Comment: Hum try to reshape the tensor so the first dimension is the batch size before getting the argmax index. `tf.reshape(model.probs, [50, -1])`

Comment: i tried using reshape in predictions variable instead of model.probs, it works now. But when i tried to print the accuracy in each epoch,the result is 
"Tensor("Mean_150:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) "

Comment: Hi @Austin, Yes that means this is a Tensor containing a single floating point value. Here it represents the accuracy. To print the content of a tensor run the operation in a session, and print the returned value. Apparently you can also use `accuracy = tf.Print(accuracy,  accuracy, message="Acc=")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Tensorflow's `tf.metrics.accuracy` function.

```
accuracy, accuracy_update_op  = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels = tf.argmax(y, axis = 2), predictions = tf.argmax(predictions, axis = 2), name = 'accuracy')
running_vars_accuracy = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope="LSTM/Accuracy")
```

`accuracy_update_op` operation will update the two local variables in each batch:

```
[<tf.Variable 'accuracy/total:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'accuracy/count:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Then, just calling `accuracy` op will print overall accuracy in each epoch:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    avg_cost_train = 0.
    total_train_batch = int((len(X_train)/(batch_size)) + 1)

    running_vars_initializer_accuracy.run()
    for _ in range(total_train_batch):
        _, miniBatchCost_train, miniBatchAccuracy_train = sess.run([trainer, loss, accuracy_update_op], feed_dict = {X: Xtrain, y: ytrain})
        avg_cost_train += miniBatchCost_train / total_train_batch
    accuracy_train = sess.run(accuracy)
```

A note here is that do not call the `tf_metric` and `tf_metric_update` in the same `session.run()` function call.